# Application of the fundamental theorem of calculus in a step of a proof

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

I am reading *Elliptic Partial Differential Equations* by Han and Lin.

I can't understand a step of the proof of Theorem 1.16, that should follow from the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. I'm sure it is trivial but I cant' see why.

We have the following equality:

\begin{equation}
\int_{B_r(0)} u(y) \  \varphi_k(y, r)\ dy = 0
\end{equation}
where $B_r(0)$ is the open ball of $\mathbb{R}^n$ centred in $0$ with radius $r >0$, $u$ is a continuous function defined on an open set $\Omega$ containing $B_r(0)$ and $\varphi_k(\cdot, r)$ is some $C^2_0(\Omega)$ function depending also on $r$.

Now we want to derive the equation with respect to $r$.
According to the book, we get:
\begin{align}
0 &= \frac{d}{dr}\Big(\int_{B_r(0)} u(y) \  \varphi_k(y, r)\ dy \Big) \\
&=\int_{\partial B_r(0)}u(y) \ \varphi_k(y,r) \ dS_y + \int_{B_r(0)} u(y) \  \frac{\partial \varphi_k(y, r)}{\partial r}\ dy.
\end{align}
where $dS_y$ is the measure on the sphere $\partial B_r(0)$.

Can you explain me this step? Thank you very much!

Comment: It is a classical trick when dealing with PDE but at the moment I can reconstruct the proof. aarrgghh

Comment: I have also the feeling to have seen it already in the past but I can't remember how it works.. :(

Comment: [...] at the moment *I can't* [...] (sorry for the spam but I am not allowed to edit my previous comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that you need to differentiate w.r.t. $r$ the following integral
$$
I(r)=\int_{B_r}f(x,r)\,dx.
$$
Define
$$
F(s,t)=\int_{B_s}f(x,t)\,dx
$$
then $I(r)=F(r,r)$, hence, the chain rule gives
$$
I'(r)=F_s'(r,r)+F_t'(r,r).
$$
Now we note that
\begin{eqnarray}
F_s'(s,t)&=&\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\int_{B_s}f(x,t)\,dx=
\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\int_0^s\left(\int_{\partial B_\sigma}f(x,t)\,dS_\sigma\right)\,dr=\int_{\partial B_s}f(x,t)\,dS_s,\\
F_t'(s,t)&=&\int_{B_s}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(x,t)\,dx
\end{eqnarray}
which are exactly the two terms in the question.